# Why does melted asiago impart a strong numbing mouthfeel?

Tags: flavor, cheese

I've put asiago in a couple dishes as of late (mac and cheese as well as a risotto) and always tend to get a strong taste accompanied by an almost ... numbing sensation in the mouth. Is this normal of asiago?

Comment: I've never experienced this. Could you have a mild allergy maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are experiencing and allergic reaction.

I got a numb palate and lips from eating sourdough with generous flour on the outside, never had that before. On googling this, it seems it's a form of intolerance. Dry flour baked on a loaf is not the usual way to ingest wheat, and there was a lot of it! Glutens and gliadins in wheat, casein in milk products as well as many other proteins can react with sensitive skin like the mouth.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! We avoid health-related topics on our site because our area of expertise is cooking, not medicine. I do agree that an allergic reaction may be involved here, but we are not in a position to judge how serious it may be. Please check out our FAQ if you want to learn more about how our site works: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: For what it's worth, there are some foods that do cause numbness or tingling on your tongue (like Sichuan pepper) but I don't think asiago is anything like that.